# Can I have one of these as well?

Tags: grammar, translation

Imagine you're in a coffee shop, you can ask for a coffee (whichever you want as follows):

> 커피 한잔 주세요

Imagine now you want also something else you see at the counter the way I would translate it would be

> 이것도 한개 주세요

Which in my mind means "Please give me one of these as well".

Question 1: Is 이것도 한개 주세요 the correct translation of "Please give me one of this as well"

Question 2: I don't really like using 주세요 many times in a row, is there an alternative expression maybe, but equivalent? What would a native say in order to avoid to be redundant.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it's a perfect one. Sounds pretty natural that I'd say the same. Some notes:

- Should be "한 잔" and "한 개." You've got to *space* the unit word and the number when writing them.
- Alternatively you can also say "하나" in place of "한 잔" or "한 개," dropping the unit.

2. Repeating the "주세요" a few times is fine; native speakers do so as well and those are more complete sentences anyways. When you're in an obvious context, such as this, you could skip the "주세요" ("give me") to avoid the repetition: e.g. "커피 한 잔이요." ("A cup of coffee, please."), "(그리고) 이것도 하나요." ("(And) this one, too.").